# UI with google docs

Tags: google-docs

This is a proof of concept I am working on. The full project is much more complex. SO this is NOT a homework or interview question.

I want to create a simple database using spreadsheet app from google doc and I want to create an interface to add/modify/delete entries in this database. Can I do it using google forms or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this which works for me: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list  . You need to create an API key, download the document, edit it and upload it back.